# How to get only first property from JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get only the selected item from this JSON file:

```
{
  "faqs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "What is Salmon about?",
      "answer": "Building great sites for our amazing clients. Simple."
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "What is the location of Salmon Watford?",
      "answer": "Just 2 minutes walk from Watford Junction Train Station"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "question": "Is this the last question?",
      "answer": "Yes. You have done well!"
    }
  ]
}
```

For example i need first question and answer to be shown in first `<div>`, second question and answer in second `<div>` and the third q & a in the third `<div>`.

I am using AJAX to access the file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'faqs.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      $(data.faqs).each(function(index, value) {
        $('#firstQuestion').text("Q: " + value.question);
        $('#firstAnswer').text(value.answer);
        $('#secondQuestion').text("Q: " + value.question);
        $('#secondAnswer').text(value.answer);
        $('#thirdQuestion').text("Q: " + value.question);
        $('#thirdAnswer').text(value.answer);
      });
    }
  });
```

And now I got some result that loops through all the items and gives me the last one but as I already said earlier I need the first question and answer at the first `<div>` and so on.

Can you provide me with some ideas or a solution? I am trying to solve this for about 4 hours now and I have nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Taplar yes I failed to notice that it's an array; I don't see what the problem is now.

Comment: `data.faqs[0]` should give you the first item in the array (assuming array length >0). Then you can access `data.faqs[0].question` to get the question of first item in the array.

Comment: @VladimirTodorov Can you provide an example of the markup the data will go in.  As is all we have is your usage of the ids.

Comment: I think the problem you are having is that it is overwriting all the html on each loop - so on the last iteration it overwrites and everything has the values of the last FAQ.

Comment: @Shyju Thank a lot, i am so stupid i did not saw that. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't even have to use the index.  `each()` is passing in the element at that index as `value`.  Though side note, you should use `$.each(yourarray)` instead of `$(array).each`.  You would use the index though to find the element on the page it should go into though most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the loop - if you are uncertain on the length of the array this will not work and you'll need a different solution like @usman-rana posted, but if you don't this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'faqs.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#firstQuestion').text("Q: " + data.faqs[0].question);
      $('#firstAnswer').text(data.faqs[0]..answer);
      $('#secondQuestion').text("Q: " + data.faqs[1]..question);
      $('#secondAnswer').text(data.faqs[1].answer);
      $('#thirdQuestion').text("Q: " + data.faqs[2].question);
      $('#thirdAnswer').text(data.faqs[2].answer);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need something like...

```js
var array = {
  "faqs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "What is Salmon about?",
      "answer": "Building great sites for our amazing clients. Simple."
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "What is the location of Salmon Watford?",
      "answer": "Just 2 minutes walk from Watford Junction Train Station"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "question": "Is this the last question?",
      "answer": "Yes. You have done well!"
    }
  ]
}

var faqs = array.faqs;

for(var i = 0; i< faqs.length; i++){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "Q : "+ faqs[i].question + " Ans: "+faqs[i].answer;
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

For your use-case, just place the javascript code in your success call back and `var faqs = data.faqs` and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that we have a function called `zip`, which takes in two arrays and returns a single array of doubles:

```
const zip = (array1, array2) => [[array1[0], array2[0]], ...]
```

`ramda`, `lodash`, and I believe `underscore` and `jquery` have this function. If not, here is a basic `zip` function:

```
const zip = (a, b) => {
  const result = []
  const maxLength = Math.max(a.length, b.length)
  for(let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    result.push(
      [a[i], b[i]]
    )
  }

  return result
}
```

Now we take in your list of ordered divs and our list of `faqs`, creating a single list of `[[div, faqObj]]`

Then we iterate over that and do our work:

```
const fullList = zip(divs, faqs)

fullList.forEach((div, obj) => {
  // do your imperative work here,
  // given a div and an object
})
```